# Flatpages equivalent for ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, django-flatpages

Django has the [Flatpages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) app, which lets site admins change content on specific pages without changing code. Flatpage content i stored in the database, sort of like in a CMS. Flatpages are typically used for about-pages and such.

Are there any good equivalents for ASP.Net MVC? I.e., a convenient way to manage page-content persisted to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Django seems closer to a CMS then "ASP.NET MVC" which is both a framework and just a general design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [http://http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com](http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com), it allows you to create pages, and manage content on the page.

The solution is still in early stages, but it could help you out.